# Using fancybox how do I link an image title to an html page?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am an artist that is using fancybox to display my gallery.  I would like people to be able to click the title of each image so that they go to separate html pages unique to each image. I would be grateful for any help.

```
<div class="span4">
  <a rel="gallery" title="Ambergris Caye • 48in X 36in • Oil on Gallery Wrapped Canvas" class="fancybox" href="images/abstract/ambergris.jpg">
    <img src="images/abstract_thumb/ambergris_thumb.jpg" alt="."class="img-polaroid" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post some code? It would be easier to understand your problem then.

Comment: HTML:<div class="span4">
           <a rel="gallery" title="Ambergris Caye • 48in X 36in • Oil on Gallery Wrapped Canvas" class="fancybox" href="images/abstract/ambergris.jpg"><img src="images/abstract_thumb/ambergris_thumb.jpg" alt="."class="img-polaroid"></a>
          </div>

Comment: I need the thumbnail to pull up the regular image with the title underneath as in the code above. What I don't know how to do is get the title text (and only the title text: "Ambergris Caye • 48in X 36in • Oil on Gallery Wrapped Canvas") to link to an html page, i.e., ambergris.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use (HTML5) `data-*` attributes in your html to pass the `link` (and optionally `title`) to be used in the fancybox `title` for each image like :

```
<div class="span4">
  <a data-link="http://google.com" data-caption="opens google" rel="gallery" title="Ambergris Caye • 48in X 36in • Oil on Gallery Wrapped Canvas" class="fancybox" href="images/image01.jpg">
    <img src="images/thumb01.jpg" alt="." class="img-polaroid" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="span4">
  <a data-link="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/" data-caption="opens bbc news" rel="gallery" title="another title here" class="fancybox" href="images/image02.jpg">
    <img src="images/thumb02.jpg" alt="." class="img-polaroid" />
  </a>
</div>
```

... etc.

Then you could use the jQuery's `.wrapInner()` method inside the fancybox's `afterShow` callback to get the info from the `data` attributes like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        $(".fancybox-title").wrapInner($("<a />", {
            href: this.element.data("link"), // link to
            title: this.element.data("caption"), // shows tooltip on mouse hover fancybox title
            target: "_blank" // optional opens in a new tab/window
        }));
    }
});
```

This will wrap the *contents* of each `.fancybox-title` (selector) with an `<a>` tag and set the relevant attributes (`href`, `title`, etc.) you need/want from the `data` attributes.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sXW25/)**

**NOTE** : the `afterShow` callback is for fancybox v2.x. If working with v1.3.4, then use `onComplete` and target the `#fancybox-title` selector instead.

Comment: WOW, thank you JFK! I appreciate your help and your time!!...  I've been messing with this and I must have something wrong because it's not working for me.  Here is my test link: http://www.jillenglish.com/gallery/test.html

Comment: @Jill : the issue you have is that you are using fancybox v1.3.4 so replace `afterShow` by `onComplete` and `$(".fancybox-title")` by `$("#fancybox-title")` in your custom script.